# Scraping ajax search engine with multiple pages in Python

Tags: python, ajax, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrap a the Korean Patent Office. However, the search engine uses ajax. What would I need to get my first results? and then how will I be able to scrap subsequent pages ?
Suppose I am searching for patents for keyword TV.

Here is my starting code. 
Any hint is highly appreciated

```
import urllib
import re


url = 'http://engpat.kipris.or.kr/engpat/searchLogina.do?next=MainSearch'
acct = open("results.txt", "w")
regex= '<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
title= re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
acct.write(title)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. One of the ways I recommend is to use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) for this task, scrape each page use XPath to select the next page element. Check Selenium docs for more examples. Regex is not the way to go with html scraping...